# click on google search button gives error ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: robotframework

Im starting with robotframework, and Im not able to get correct selector for google search button. What Im doing wrong?

```
*** Settings ***
    Documentation                                      This is a basic test
    Library                                            SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}                                              https://www.google.com
${browser}                                          chrome
${text}                                             css:input[name=q]
${search_button}                                    css:input[name=btnK]

${expected_result}                                  Test


*** Test Cases ***


User fill in the Search text box
    [Documentation]                                 The user search 'Test'
    open browser                                    ${url}  ${browser}
    wait until page contains                        ${url}
    input text                                      ${text}  test
    click button                                    ${search_button} 
    wait until page contains                        ${expected_result}
    sleep     5s
    close browser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be perfect except the last part of clicking on search button. Also the indented import looks odd to me. May be its only me but I got error on that line in VS Code. Once I fixed that(just removed indentation). Actual problem of clicking on Search button will be solve by [`Press Keys`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys) keyword of selenium library. When we type something in the search box the autosuggestion overrides the search button. Instead of getting rid of dropdown just press the enter key as in below code -

```
User fill in the Search text box
[Documentation]                                 The user search 'Test'
open browser                                    ${url}  ${browser}
wait until page contains                        ${url}
input text                                      ${text}  test
Press keys            ${text}      RETURN
wait until page contains                        ${expected_result}
sleep     5s
```